# Rails helper module undefined method `sort'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a simple helper module in rails, and I'm stumped on the following error message from my new person form (app/views/people/new.html.erb):

```
undefined method `sort' for 97:Fixnum

Extracted source (around line #17):

14:   <p>
15:         <% nations = { 'United States of America' => 'USA', 'Canada' => 'Canada', 'Mexico' => 'Mexico', 'United Kingdom' => 'UK' } %>
16:     <%= f.label :country %><br />
17:         <%= radio_buttons(:person, :country, nations) %>
18:         
19:   </p>
20:   <p>
```

radio_buttons is a helper module I have created for my view.  Here it is (app/helpers/people_helper.rb):

```
module PeopleHelper 

def radio_buttons(model_name, target_property, button_source) 
  html='' 
  list = button_source.sort 
  list.each do |x| 
    html << radio_buttons(model_name, target_property, x[1]) 
    html << h(x[0]) 
    html << '<br />' 
  end 
  return html 
end 

end
```

The problem appears to be on the "list = button_source.sort", but I'm not sure why it says the method is undefined.  I have been able to use it directly within my view code.  Am I not able to use methods like this within helper modules?  Do I need to include something?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line `html << radio_buttons(model_name, target_property, x[1])` the method calls itself recursively. This time the third argument is no longer a hash, but `x[1]` which is a Fixnum. And since Finxums don't respond to `sort` you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

`undefined method 'sort' for 97:Fixnum` means that 97, an instance of `Fixnum`, does not have a `sort` method.  For some reason, the parameter `button_source` in your method is coming in as an integer.

A quick fix would be to write `list = Array(button_source).sort` which will coerce `button_source` to an `Array`, because `Array`s are the most common class that has the `sort` method.  If `button_source` is already an `Array`, nothing will be changed.

Comment: This got me past the sort error, so thanks!  However, now I'm getting a "stack level too deep" error.  My recursion appears to be problematic.